# Determining the type of conic and drawing a graph of it

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

What type of conic is given by the equation:

$x^2+2xy+y^2-1=0$

And draw a graph of the conic.

My method was to compute the intersection of the conic with the line at infinity, and got $x=-y$ so we have one point of intersection and hence it is a parabola? I noticed that the symmetric matrix for this conic is singular so this means the conic is degenerate. So is it still a parabola? Would the graph just be a line?

Comment: It's the union of two lines $$(x+y+1)(x+y-1)=0$$

Comment: The Wikipedia article is pretty good on conic sections. Read the General Cartesian Form and the Discriminant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section

Answer (score 1):

The equation factors as

$$(x+y)^2-1=(x+y+1)(x+y-1)=0$$ and describes a pair of parallel straight lines.

Answer (score 1):

$${ \left( x+y \right)  }^{ 2 }=1\\ y=\pm 1-x$$ they are parallel lines