# Pair of lines problem

Tags: geometry

If the pair of straight lines $x^2+2xy+ay^2$ & $ax^2+2xy+y^2$ have exactly one line in common, then the combined equation of the two lines is given by

A. $3x^2+8xy-3y^2$

B. $3x^2+10xy+3y^2$

C.  $-3x^2+2xy+y^2$

D. $x^2+2xy-3y^2$

My approach
Let the equation of lines are

lx+my=0(Common line)

px+qy=0..Line 1

rx+ty=0..Line 2

Equation of line 1 and common line

$lpx^2+(lq+mp)xy+mqy^2=0$

Equation of line 2 and common line

$rlx^2+(lt+rm)xy+tmy^2=0$

Not able to compare it with the question.

Comment: I don't understand ... Shouldn't the equation of a line be an equation with an $=$-sign? How is just the number $x^2 + 2xy + ay^2$ a straight line?

Comment: @ Matti P. see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311197

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

If $x^2+2 x y + a y^2$ and $a x^2+2 x y + y^2$ have a common linear factor, then

$$
x^2+2 x y + a y^2-(a x^2+2 x y + y^2) = (1-a) x^2 -(1-a) y^2 = (1-a)(x^2-y^2) = (1-a)(x+y)(x-y)
$$

has this same factor.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $x=p$ is the common root

$$p^2+2py+ay^2=0$$ and $$ap^2+2py+y^2=0$$

Solve for $p,p^2$

Use $p^2=(p)^2$ to eliminate $p$